# filter paths that have only one "/" in R using regular expression

Tags: r, regex, string, filter, path

I have a vector of different paths such as

```
 levs<-c( "20200507-30g_25d" , "20200507-30g_25d/ggg" , "20200507-30g_25d/grn", "20200507-30g_25d/ylw", "ggg" , "grn", "tre_livelli", "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d", "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d/ggg", "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d/grn", "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d/ylw" , "ylw" )
```

which is actually the output of a list.dirs with recursive set to TRUE.

I want to identify only the paths which have just one subfolder (that is "20200507-30g_25d/ggg" , "20200507-30g_25d/grn", "20200507-30g_25d/ylw").

I thought to filter the vector to find only those paths that have only one "/" and then compare the this with the ones that have more than one "/" to get rid of the partial paths.

I tried with regular expression such as:

```
rep(levs,pattern='/{1}', value=T)
```

but I get this:

```
 "20200507-30g_25d/ggg"             "20200507-30g_25d/grn"             "20200507-30g_25d/ylw"             "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d"     "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d/ggg" "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d/grn" "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d/ylw"
```

Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/{1}` is a regex that is equal to `/` and just matches a `/` anywhere in a string, and there can be more than one `/` inside it. Please have a look at the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) [tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info):

> Using `{1}` as a single-repetition quantifier is harmless but never useful. It is basically an indication of inexperience and/or confusion.
>
> `h{1}t{1}t{1}p{1}` matches the same string as the simpler expression `http` (or `ht{2}p` for that matter) but as you can see, the redundant `{1}` repetitions only make it harder to read.

You can use

```r
grep(levs, pattern="^[^/]+/[^/]+$", value=TRUE)
# => [1] "20200507-30g_25d/ggg"         "20200507-30g_25d/grn"         "20200507-30g_25d/ylw"         "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjHoTU/1):

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `[^/]+`- one or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]+`- one or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: if the parts before or after the only `/` in the string can be empty, replace `+` with `*`: `^[^/]*/[^/]*$`.

Answer (score 3):

An option with `str_count` to count the number of instances of `/`

```
library(stringr)
levs[str_count(levs, "/") == 1 ]
```

-ouptut

```
[1] "20200507-30g_25d/ggg"         "20200507-30g_25d/grn" 
[3] "20200507-30g_25d/ylw"         "tre_livelli/20200507-30g_25d"
```